# make the 2nd line fill up the gaps above

Tags: html, css

A simple html/css issue. Please look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bLUrU/1/), I would like the blocks in the 2nd line to fill up the gaps above them. Anyway besides using JavaScript?

```
.block {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
<div style="width: 606px;">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript to re-arrange the position instead of using `float: left`

Comment: @Raptor JavaScript would do the job, I'm just worrying about there would be trouble resizing page. But as it's the only solution, I'll have to do it ;)

Comment: add event listener on browser resize if needed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm going to do. Just wondering if there were easier ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple answer, NO.

(sorry)

This cannot be accomplished in vanilla HTML or CSS alone, you will need to look into a JavaScript implementation like [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) or [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/), or one of your own making.

Comment: Get it. Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using CSS3, then maybe columns can help you to get the blocks stack up.

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bLUrU/5/*

*Example CSS*:

```
.container {
    -webkit-columns: 3;        /* create three columns */
    -webkit-column-gap: 2px;   /* have 2px gap between the columns */
}
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* avoid breaking contents across columns */
}
```

Add other vendor prefixes as required apart from `-webkit`.

Of course, by using columns you would have to relook the ordering of your `div`s. *Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bLUrU/6/*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't use CSS3 in this project.

Answer (score 0):

add `float:right` to the third block

```
<div style="width: 606px;">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height: 250px;float:right;">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
</div>
```